# cache webpage in case site is down

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a static webpage that is cached in the browser. However when I take down the website the browser gives a 404 error.
I'm using the manifest attribute in HTML like so.

```
<html manifest="manifest.appcache">
<head>
    <title>Connection Verification</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Testing Connection...</h3>
</body>
```

my manifest.appcache looks like this.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#Nothing to load here
```

I assume the top level HTML file is implied.

I am also sending the cache-control header in the response.

```
cache-control: public max-age:3153600
```

However when I bring down the webserver and reload the page it still gives a 404 error.  Is there some way to force browser to cache?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 AppCache: how to implement offline mode if server isn't accessible but network is accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506532/html5-appcache-how-to-implement-offline-mode-if-server-isnt-accessible-but-net)

Comment: Note that appCache is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/applicationCache)